# Publishing package under different account

Tags: npm, npm-publish

Is it possible to publish new version of an **npm package** under different **npm account** name.

I have created a npm package published under my account name, but now the whole project has been migrated to my organization's git profile and we would like to have this packages published now with organization account.

Is this possible, and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Actually answer is quite trivial, just use:

```
npm owner add ACCOUNT_NAME
```

**UPDATE:**
Cool bonus is that if you've already published package under your name, if will still remain under your account as well. So now the package has two publishers. Also organization gets linked to previous versions retroactively.

Comment: Do you have to use the `@` symbol if it is an organization?

Comment: No, just standard org account name. If you are referring to @something/package-name naming convention, that's all in the package.json settings